# How to save file as mp3 from Amazon Polly using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I am using Amazon Polly for TTS, but I am not able to get how to save the converted speech into a .mp3 file in my computer

I have tried gTTS but i require Amazon Polly for my task.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('polly')
response = client.synthesize_speech
(Text = "Hello my name is Shubham", OuptutFormat = "mp3", VoiceId = 'Aditi')
```

Now, what Should I do to play this converted speech or save it into my PC as .mp3 file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code sample is taken straight from the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/SynthesizeSpeechSamplePython.html

```
import boto3

polly_client = boto3.Session(
                aws_access_key_id=,                     
    aws_secret_access_key=,
    region_name='us-west-2').client('polly')

response = polly_client.synthesize_speech(VoiceId='Joanna',
                OutputFormat='mp3', 
                Text = 'This is a sample text to be synthesized.')

file = open('speech.mp3', 'wb')
file.write(response['AudioStream'].read())
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I play the output without saving it into the file?

Comment: To play audio from Python, look at libraries like [PyAudio · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/) and [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/).

Comment: Another code example form AWS documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/get-started-what-next.html

Answer (score 1):

While not directly related to the original question, I responded to one of the comments about hot to get to the audio stream without saving the audio to a file.

You might also check out the documentation for this example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/example-Python-server-code.html

This shows getting the response back from Polly:

```
    response = polly.synthesize_speech(Text=text, VoiceId=voiceId, OutputFormat=outputFormat)
    data_stream=response.get("AudioStream")
```

The first line makes the request to Polly and stores the response in the response object, while the second line gets the audio stream from the response object.